# TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new viewClass()')

Tags: angular, nativescript, angular2-nativescript

I am using [nativescript-intro-slides](https://github.com/TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-slides) library, I followed the angular example as [mentioned](https://github.com/TheOriginalJosh/nativescript-slides/issues/37#issuecomment-224820901) but I am facing this error:

```
    class ListComponent - inline template:1:8 ORIGINAL EXCEPTION: 
TypeError: undefined is not a constructor (evaluating 'new viewClass()') 
ORIGINAL STACKTRACE: createAndAttach@file:///app/tns_modules/nativescript-angular/view-util.js:90:33
```

My code:

```
import {Component,ElementRef, OnInit, ViewChild} from "@angular/core";
import {registerElement} from "nativescript-angular/element-registry";
registerElement("Slide", () => require("nativescript-intro-slides").Slide);
registerElement("SlideContainer", () => require("nativescript-intro-slides").SlideContainer);

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: "List-page",
    template: `
        <SlideContainer angular="true" #slides>
            <Slide *ngFor="let img of images">
                <Label [text]="img.title"></Label>
            </Slide>
        </SlideContainer>
    `
})

export class ListComponent implements OnInit {
    public images: Array<any> = [];
    @ViewChild("slides") slides: ElementRef;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.images.push({title: 'Sports'});
        this.images.push({title: 'Cats'});
        this.images.push({title: 'Food'});
    }
    ngAfterViewInit() {
        let SlidesXml = this.slides.nativeElement;
        SlidesXml.constructView();
    }
}
```

plus I could not find the method constructView.
Thank you

Comment: Can you show the parent component where `ListComponent` is called?

Comment: It is a main component

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`nativescript-intro-slides` library has a lot of problems so its owner recommends using the new version `nativescript-slides`

[image]